# Why does extracting a value from nested SparkDataframe changes the value?

Tags: apache-spark, serialization

I have a SparkDataframe of type  (it represents a graph with weighted edges). To process it as `GraphFrame`, the `TestObjects` have to be unnested and renamed. However, the transformation of the Dataframe into a list of edges seems to change the 'id' values of the object. How can I avoid this?

Here is TestObject:

```
public class TestObject implements Serializable {

private Long identification;
private String anotherField;

public TestObject() {
}

public TestObject(Long id) {
    this.identification = id;
    this.anotherField = "anotherField";
}

public void setIdentification(Long identification) {
    this.identification = identification;
}
public Long getIdentification() {
    return identification;
}
public String getAnotherField() { 
    return anotherField;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
    TestObject that = (TestObject) o;
    return Objects.equals(identification, that.identification);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
            .append(identification)
            .append(anotherField)
            .build();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return identification.toString();
}
}
```

The transformation int `DataSet<Row>` with appropriate field names:

```
String columnNameID = "identification";
Dataset<Row> edges = input.
            select( col("_1." + columnNameID).as(SRC()),
                    col("_2." + columnNameID).as(DST()),
                    col("_3"));
```

Example code:

```
    // Create 5 TestObjects with ids in [0, 4]
    List<TestObject> expectedVertices = LongStream.range(0, 5).mapToObj(TestObject::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // each tuple is of type (sourceID, destinationID, similarity)
    List<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, Double>> edgesIDList = Arrays.asList(new Tuple3<>(0, 1, 0.2d),
            new Tuple3<>(1, 2, 0.6d), new Tuple3<>(1, 4, 0.5d), new Tuple3<>(2, 3, 0.0d), new Tuple3<>(2, 4, 0.3d),
            new Tuple3<>(3, 4, 0.5d));

    // map IDs to TestObjects
    List<Tuple3<TestObject, TestObject, Double>> inputEdges = edgesIDList.stream()
            .map(triple -> new Tuple3<>(expectedVertices.get(triple._1()), expectedVertices.get(triple._2()),
                    triple._3()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Convert to dataset
    Dataset<Tuple3<TestObject, TestObject, Double>> inputEdgesDataset = spark.createDataset(inputEdges,
            Encoders.tuple(OBJECT_ENCODER, OBJECT_ENCODER, Encoders.DOUBLE()));

    inputEdgesDataset.printSchema();
    inputEdgesDataset.collectAsList().forEach(System.out::println);
```

After running the example code, I get the following output:

```
root
 |-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- anotherField: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- identification: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- anotherField: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- identification: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: double (nullable = true)

(0,5,0.2)
(0,5,0.6)
(0,5,0.5)
(0,5,0.0)
(0,5,0.3)
(0,5,0.5)
```

But after the transformation it looks like this:

```
root
 |-- src: long (nullable = true)
 |-- dst: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: double (nullable = true)

[0,9,0.2]
[0,13,0.6]
[0,13,0.5]
[0,13,0.0]
[0,13,0.3]
[0,13,0.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I could solve the problem by adding the `setAnotherField` method to `TestObject`. That gives the right values from the beginning (the ids are already wrong before changing mysteriously). So it seems to be about serialization and incomplete POJOs. I would be glad if anybody could provide some further explanation regarding my error and the solution.